# nodejs- kafka-node module- getting the same msg from each partition

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm using node module "kafka-node" to create a kafa-consumer:

```
var client = new kafka.Client(ZOO_KEEPER_URL, PORTAL_CLIENT_ID);
var topics = [
      { "topic" : MY_TOPIC_NAME,
        partition: 0
      },
      { "topic" : MY_TOPIC_NAME,
        partition: 1      }
    ];
var options = {
      autoCommit: false,
      groupId: GROUP_ID,
      fromOffset : false
    };
var consumer = new Consumer(client, topics, options);
    consumer.on('message', function (message) {
       console.log("New Message; offset: "+ message.offset + " Partition:   "+message.partition);           
    });
```

What happens is the same offset is retrieved once from partition 0, and then from partition 1. 
What I expected is ZooKeeper will know how to balance and manage this.

**Note:**
The use case is reading from any available msg from Kafka -> writting to Elastic Search -> committing to Kafka (that's why autocommit is set to false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each partition has its own offset and contains different data. Thus, if you receive a message with offset zero from partition 0 and a message with offset zero from partition 1, it is two different messages. Also on commit, the offsets of all partitions are stored independently.

Comment: you're absolutely right, thanks. What I don't understand now is the offset API- What is the relation between the earliest offset available I get when calling-  var offset = new kafka.Offset(client);   offset.fetch([{
        "topic" : topicName
      }]  and the offsets the partitions manage?

Comment: If a consumer starts, it has two possibilities to start reading: either from the latest committed offset or from the end of the topic. (see parameter "auto.offset.reset"). Of course, you can also seek to any position for reading, too. Commit offsets is usually use to ensure no message is lost in case a client fails -- ie, on recovery, the client can resume from the latest committed offsets.